# Can't select any items from the left pane of Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I am having a strange problem with Xcode. I don't know how that appeared. In the Organiser window of my Xcode, I can switch between tabs like Devices, Repositories, Archives, Documentation etc. But in every tab, the top item of the left pane is always selected. For example, in the Repository tab, the repository on the top of left pane is always selected. Same goes for others. Such as, in the Devices tab, "Software Images" is always selected.

I can't select any other item from the left pane of any tab of Organizer, as the top one is always selected. If I right click on any of them, that works and "Organiser Help" menu is shown accordingly. And if I tap on expand/collapse icon for any item in the left pane, that works and the item is expanded and collapsed accordingly. But I can't select anything for expanded condition as well. Doesn't matter whether an item is collapsed or expanded, problem is, I can't select that item anyhow with trackpad, mouse, keyboard, anything.

I am running Xcode 4.6.3 in OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.3 in Macbook Pro.

Comment: Have you tried properly closing the app and restarting it?

Comment: Yes , I did several times. And now I also notice that I can't pull/push to remote repository from Xocde which I have been doing so far. When I try to pull/push , it stays on grayed "Loading remote repository" and it doesn't find that. But I can pull/push from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the problem again next day. So, hopefully rebooting my mac has solved the problem. Everything is working good now.